# Get AlertDialog view of WebView

Tags: android, cordova, junit, webview

I'm creating a scenario test framework for Android Cordova/PhoneGap applications that builds on JUnit. There is one scenario I would like to test: you click on some button in the webpage (shown in an Android WebView) and it opens a popup (an AlertDialog). I want to check the message on this popup and click one of the buttons. Therefore I need the view object of this AlertDialog.

I know you can use findViewById, but you have to give an id as parameter, which I don't have since the dialog is created with the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx.getContext());
dlg.setMessage(message);
dlg.setTitle(title);
....
dlg.create();
dlg.show();
```

Any idea how I can access the correct view?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `TextView` containing the `AlertDialog`'s message is always identified by `android.R.id.message`. If you capture the result of `dlg.create()`, you should be able to get a reference to the message `TextView` by calling `.findViewById(android.R.id.message)` on it, from which you could then get the text.

Comment: The problem is that I cannot capture the result of `dlg.create()` since it is part of the PhoneGap/Cordova core. Maybe I can adapt it in my proof of concept.